# Are there any cheats in Half-Life: Alyx?

Tags: cheats, half-life-alyx

The classic Half-Life games (and other games with the same engine) had a console and various cheat commands to enter there. Is this the case for Half-Life: Alyx as well?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Alyx has the same kind of cheats like the classic Half-Life games.

To enable them, launch the game with the command line arguments `-console -vconsole` ("Set Launch Options" in the game properties in Steam). This will allow you to open the console using the <kbd>~</kbd> key (on an en_US keyboard; if you have a different one try whatever is left of <kbd>1</kbd>).

When pressing they key, the console shows up on your screen, not inside VR - so you may want to pause the game (because after all) and take off your VR headset. Inside the console you can type various commands in the text field labelled "Commands".

First of all, you want to run `sv_cheats 1` to enable cheats. Once that's done, the following (and likely more!) cheats are available:

- `god` - doesn't really need any explanation, but it makes you invulnerable. Time to cuddle some headcrabs?
- `buddha` - you still take damage, but you won't die when losing all your health points
- `impulse 101` - gives you all three weapons, and also 20 resin.
- `impulse 102` - gives you all weapon upgrades
- `sv_infinite_ammo 1` - gives you unlimited ammo, but you still need to reload
- `sv_infinite_clips 1` - if you want a less fun game, and never reload, this one is for you. PS: you still can't kill Jeff.
- `hlvr_shotgun_grant_upgrades 3` - get the shotgun with all upgrades

Infinite ammo or clip size can be disabled again by setting them to `0` instead of `1`. God/Buddha mode are toggles, so just run those again.

Comment: Is this an exhaustive list or are there other commands that could be considered cheats?

Comment: It's the cheat commands known so far. I'm pretty sure there are more!

Comment: There's this thing where you wiggle your controller or the buttons/sticks on it in a certain way, the game teleports you to 0,0,0 on the map. You can see this in use on some speedruns.